# Oracle SQL Error ORA-00933

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to determine if a column is a primary key in oracle database.

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT cols.column_name 
FROM all_constraints as cons, all_cons_columns as cols 
WHERE (cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
       AND cols.columnName= 'SRC_CODE' 
       AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' 
       AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
       AND cons.owner = cols.owner 
       AND cons.status = 'ENABLED' 
       AND lower(cons.owner)='resmaid') 
ORDER BY cols.table_name
```

I get the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:852)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1477)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:392)
```

There was a time this sql may have worked, cant just remember when (about 2 years ago).

This is urgent as i need to connect to this database and do some data insertion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed it.

Two things.
1. Remove "AS" used in alias to table names
2. column_name is misspelled in where clause

Please see below

```
SELECT cols.column_name
  FROM all_constraints cons,
  all_cons_columns   cols
  WHERE (cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
    AND cols.column_Name = 'SRC_CODE'
    AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
    AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
    AND cons.owner = cols.owner
    AND cons.status = 'ENABLED'
    AND lower(cons.owner) = 'resmaid')
 ORDER BY cols.table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT cols.column_name
 --modify FROM all_constraints as cons, all_cons_columns as cols  
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols 
WHERE (cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
       --modify AND cols.columnName= 'SRC_CODE'  
       AND cols.column_name= 'SRC_CODE' 
       AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' 
       AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
       AND cons.owner = cols.owner 
       AND cons.status = 'ENABLED' 
       AND lower(cons.owner)='resmaid') 
ORDER BY cols.table_name
```